# Removing part of an image src

Tags: jquery, image, replace, src

Using jQuery, I've created a simple lightbox which loads an image upon clicking a thumbnail.

I'm trying to get the lightbox to work by storing the thumbnail src as a variable from which to load the main gallery image. The variable however, needs the '/thumbs' part of the src removing to find the larger gallery image.

I've followed numerous answers already given to variants of this question, but none of my attempts to emulate the results seem to work.

I've gotten as far as this:

```
$("#attractions-dave li a").live("click", function showAttraction(e){

 var example = $(this).children('img').attr('src', $(this).children('img').attr('src').replace('/thumbs',''));      

});
```

For reference, the associated html is:

```
<ul id="attractions-dave">
 <li>
  <a href="../attractions/attractions.php">
   <img src="../images/photos/bouncy-castles/thumbs/happyclown.jpg" alt="happy clown castle" />
  </a>
 </li>
</ul>
```

Once I have got the variable, I am using it to set a background image, using the following code:

```
$('#example').css('background-image', 'url(' + example + ')');
```

As of now, the code simply doesn't add any background css to the element.

I'm not receiving any errors with this code, but it's clear that the variable (the amended thumbnail src) isn't being recognised.

If anyone can see where I'm going wrong, then any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What jquery version are you using? `live` is not longer valid since v1.9

Comment: Currently using 1.7.1.

Comment: Please explain in more details what exactly is your goal. Once you get the "new" src without "/thumbs" - do you want to replace the thumb image with the large one? Or do you want do pass this new src to some other function?

Comment: Sorry yeah, I've just added further clarification to Roasted's answer. Once I've got the variable, I'm using it to set a background image. I'll update the question with the code.

Comment: So, what is `$('#example')`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`example` in your code is a jQuery object. You need to do:

```
var example = $(this).children('img').attr('src').replace('/thumbs','');
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to prevent default behaviour:

http://jsfiddle.net/eYJ7L/

```
$("#attractions-dave li a").live("click", function showAttraction(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var example = $(this).children('img').attr('src', $(this).children('img').attr('src').replace('/thumbs', ''));

});
```

Comment: I'm afraid I'm having no success on my end. Would it help to know that I'm using the variable to set a background image using the following code:

    $('#example').css('background-image', 'url(' + example + ')');

Comment: What would help will be you provide a jsfiddle with relevant HTML code too

Comment: `$('#example').css('background-image', 'url("' + example + '")');` Test that

Comment: Hey roasted, thanks a lot for your help (I'd nearly finished the fiddle too), but David nailed it. Thanks for your time though.

Comment: I'll certainly make a point of including a fiddle by default in future. Sorry if you feel I wasted your time, but again, thank you for your assistance.

Comment: NP, Dave, i'll be glad to help you again :)